# How to convert a n-ary tree to a complete k-ary tree?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

This is a tree question:

The input is a n-ary tree's root and integer k. n-ary may not be a full tree. How to convert this n-ary tree to a omplete k-ary tree?

The tree class can be something like this:

```
class Tree {
 int val;
 List<Tree> children;
}
```

Comment: @greybeard Just updated my title and summary.

Comment: Even for numbers *n* of nodes with *k* ≤ *n*, building a **full** *k*-ary tree is not always possible: Can you give a condition for *n* depending on *k* as to when it is?  How would you start for a first node? What if there are any (*n*-ary) nodes left?

Comment: @greybeard I think the last level of a full tree doesn't need to be full, right? As long as the rest levels are full, we can call it a full tree.

Comment: Cite a definition of *full k-ary tree* and/or link one.

Comment: @greybeard, my bad, should be a complete k-ary tree. I updated my post. https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html

Comment: Different indeed (and not at all trivial depending on additional constraints such as input and output being *search trees*) - I seem to remember seeing it discussed here or at CS@SE. (The picture in the [2019 en.wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) is better for not presenting a *perfect* binary tree as an example of a *full* tree - pity [*k*-ary tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) doesn't contain any.)

Comment: Here a [solution for k=2 and a funny constraint on *keys*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105817). (It may be non-obvious why(if?) that always constructs a complete tree.)